# Matching variable string with Lua

Tags: regex, lua, match, openresty

I'm fighting with the file search script
The `x99999999` value is continuously variable. How can I find this value with lua match?
I need to find and change this variable.

```
/home/data_x99999999_abc_def_0.sh
```

I actually have code that works but I'm not sure it's a correct regex.

```
local newpath = s:gsub("(_x)[^_]*(_)", "_static_")
```

Comment: this is very similar to your earlier question, you probably should have edited they earlier question with these details. `"_(x%d+)_"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure it's a correct regex.

Lua patterns are no regular expressions. Compared to regular expressions Lua's string pattens have a different syntax and are more limited.

Your code

```
local newpath = s:gsub("(_x)[^_]*(_)", "_static_")
```

replaces `"_x"` followed by 0 or more non-underscore characters followed by `"_"` with `"_static_"`

This is correct but not very elegant.

1. the captures `()` are not necessary as you don't make use of them. So `"_x[^_]*_"` would achieve the same.
2. if you know that only the x12345678 part changes and that there are only digits after x  you can simply use `"x%d+"` and repalce it with `"static"`. This matches `"x"` followed by 1 or more digits. Or you include the underscores.
3. if you only want to match exactly 8 digits you could use `"%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d"` or `string.rep("%d",8)`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I wanted to tell you exactly that. I'm trying to write clean codes